# How to compare a search query to SVD resulting 'w' matrix

Tags: python, vector, vectorization, tf-idf, svd

I am working on developing a search algorithm and I am struggling to understand how to actually use the results of a singular value decomposition ( u,w,vt = svd(a) ) reduction on a term-document matrix.

For example, say I have an M x N matrix as follows where each column represents a document vector (number of terms in each document)

```
a = [[ 0, 0, 1 ],
     [ 0, 1, 2 ],
     [ 1, 1, 1 ],
     [ 0, 2, 3 ]]
```

Now, I could run a tf-idf function on this matrix to generate a score for each term/document value, but for the sake of clarity, I will ignore that.

**SVD Results**

Upon running SVD on this matrix, I end up with the following diagonal vector for 'w'

```
import svd

u,w,vt = svd.svd(a)
print w

// [4.545183973611469, 1.0343228430392626, 0.5210363733873331]
```

I understand more or less what this represents (thanks to a lot of reading and particularly this article https://simonpaarlberg.com/post/latent-semantic-analyses/), however I can't figure out how to relate this resulting 'approximation' matrix back to the original documents? What do these weights represent? How can I use this result in my code to find documents related to a term query?

Basically... How do I use this?

Answer (score 0):

The rank-*r* SVD reduces a rank-*R* *M*x*N* matrix *A* into *r* orthogonal rank-1 *M*x*N* matrices (*u_n* * *s_n* * *v_n*'). If you use these singular values and vectors to reconstruct the original matrix, you will obtain the best rank-*r* approximation of *A*.

Instead of storing the full matrix *A*, you just store the *u_n*, *s_n*, and *v_n*. (*A* is *M*x*N*, but *U* is *M*x*r*, *S* can be stored in one dimension as *r* elements, and *V*' is *r*x*N*).

To approximate *A* * *x*, you simply compute (*U* * (*S* * (*V'* * *x*))) [*M*x*r* x *r*x*r* x *r*x*N* x *N*x1]. You can speed this up further by storing (*U* * *S*) instead of *U* and *S* separately.

So what do the singular values represent? In a way, they represent the *energy* of each rank-1 matrix. The higher a singular value is, the more that its associated rank-1 matrix contributes to the original matrix and the worse your reconstruction will be if it is not included if it is truncated.

Note that this procedure is closely related to [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), which is performed on covariance matrices and is commonly used in machine learning to reduce the dimensionality of measured *N*-dimensional variables.

Additionally, it should be noted that the SVD is useful for many other applications in signal processing.

More information is on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: Thank you @rlbond, I think that is starting to make some sense. I'm using gensim, which really does all the work for me, but I really want to understand the underlying math as well. I think I just need more time studying the topic to get my head wrapped around it.